# Square mesh steps

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's have a square mesh, endless in all directions, in which you can move through with the following steps:

- ${[x, y] \Rightarrow  [x+1, y]}$
- ${[x, y] \Rightarrow  [x-1, y]}$
- ${[x, y] \Rightarrow  [x, y+1]}$
- ${[x, y] \Rightarrow  [x, y-1]}$

Determine how many different ways you can get with 12 steps from point ${[0, 0]}$ to ${[3,5]}$.

Can someone please provide a step by step solution for this?

Disclaimer: this is not a homework exercise

Comment: I'm for thirty-two... But I'll never be able to demonstrate such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're allowed to reach $(3,5)\;$more than once, provided you end up at $(3,5)\;$after $12\;$steps.

Let $h,v\;$be the number of horizontal and vertical steps, respectively.

Clearly, we must have $h \ge 3,\;$and $v \ge 5$.

Let $R,L,U,D\;$be the number of steps which go right, left, up, down, respectively.

Then we have the equations
$$h = R+L,\;\;R-L = 3\tag{1}$$
$$v = U + D,\;\;U-D = 5\tag{2}$$
For any pair of integers $a,b,\;$the parity of $a+b\;$is the same as the parity of $a-b\;$(i.e., $a+b\;$and $a-b\;$are either both even, or both odd.

Thus, since $R-L\;$is odd, $h\;$must be odd. Similarly, since $U-D\;$is odd, $v\;$must be odd.

Hence we have only $3\;$cases . . .

Case $(1)$:$\;h=3,v=9$.

From $(1),\;$we get $R=3,L=0,\;$and from $(2),\;$we get $U=7,D=2,\;$hence for this case, the number of qualifying paths is
$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{0}\binom{9}{7}\binom{2}{2}=7920$$
Case $(2)$:$\;h=5,v=7$.

From $(1),\;$we get $R=4,L=1,\;$and from $(2),\;$we get $U=6,D=1,\;$hence for this case, the number of qualifying paths is
$$\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{6}\binom{1}{1}=27720$$
Case $(3)$:$\;h=7,v=5$.

From $(1),\;$we get $R=5,L=2,\;$and from $(2),\;$we get $U=5,D=0,\;$hence for this case, the number of qualifying paths is
$$\binom{12}{5}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{5}\binom{0}{0}=16632$$

Hence, the total number of qualifying paths is
$$7920+27720+16632=52272$$